Azure migration pick only changed work item
I am migration few work items form TFS to Devops and while checking few work items "Iteration path" went wrong because of deleting few child items unknowingly.
IS there any way to run JSON script again so that changed work item alone should pick which will save lot of time.
I thried this field ""WorkItemPostProcessingContext": true," but this not giving any effect.
Is there any field which can auto correct changed items in Devops compated to TFS
My Code
 "Processors": [
{
  "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
  "Enabled": true,
  "ReplayRevisions": true,
  "PrefixProjectToNodes": true,
  "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
  "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
  //"WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('bug')",
  "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'user story' AND [System.Id] = 72235",
  "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
  "LinkMigration": true,
  "AttachmentMigration": true,
  "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
  "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": true,
  "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
  "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
  "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
  "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
  "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
  "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
  "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
  "GenerateMigrationComment": false,
  "WorkItemIDs": null,
  "MaxRevisions": 0,
  "NodeStructureEnricherEnabled": true,
  "UseCommonNodeStructureEnricherConfig": false,
  "ShouldCreateMissingRevisionPaths": true,
  "UpdateSourceReflectedWorkItemID": true,
  "NodeBasePaths": null,
  "AreaMaps": {},
  "IterationMaps": {
  },
  "MaxGracefulFailures": 0,
  "SkipRevisionWithInvalidIterationPath": false,
  "SkipRevisionWithInvalidAreaPath": false,
  "ShouldCreateNodesUpFront": true,
  "ReplicateAllExistingNodes": false
}


Can you share more details about the current settings of the json script? Do you mean that you need to migrate part of the work items?  What exactly has been changed in the work item you mentioned? If possible, can you share a smple?

I want to fetch the changed item of a user story or bug, FOr me Iteratoin path is changed for few items

Can you confirm whether the work items have been migrated to Azure DevOps or only exist in tfs? Do you mean that you need to automatically change the iteration path during the migration process?

As far as I know, the WorkItemPostProcessingContext can use  wiql to filter the work items.  Can you share more info about why it doesn't work?

Editec my question with Json code part

From your updated info, do you mean that you need to only migrate the work items with the iteration path: .....\Sprint 44 to azure devops service? And what issues do you encounter when using the current json file that made it unable to meet your needs?

While running current JSON I am not able to correct the iteration path. I want the Json to update the wrong field eg: iteration path.
My requirment is to update the fileds which is different than source item

I already migrated all the items but few items Iteration path is wrong so I want to run the  JSON to auto correct wrong items. Is there any parameter I can add in JSON so that it auto correct the wrong field

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am afraid that the azure devops migration tool can not correct the already migrated work items in Azure DevOps. To correct the items iteration, you can use script to run rest api to modify the work items in bulk. You can provide the iteration information from .... to .... I can help you write the script.

Thanks for your great support, but my target location have few items which belongs there and few came from different sources, So really finding the items are difficult. I thought to re-run Json so it will correct automatically.

I can understand your requirement, but it does not support re-use of Azure DevOps migration tools to change already migrated work items again.

@Sijith this is a very old version of the config and will not work with the latest version.

You can use the query to filter only work items that have changed since the date provided. You can add any date or time that you need. This is a standard WIQL query and cant contain any filters, however the standard WIQL tags of @today will not work.
    {
      "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "WIQLQuery": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.ChangedDate] > '2024-01-01' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan','Shared Steps','Shared Parameter','Feedback Request') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": true,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
      "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
      "WorkItemIDs": null,
      "MaxGracefulFailures": 0,
      "SkipRevisionWithInvalidIterationPath": false,
      "SkipRevisionWithInvalidAreaPath": false
    },

The key bit is the query itself:
SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.ChangedDate] > '2024-01-01' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan','Shared Steps','Shared Parameter','Feedback Request') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc
And specifically the [System.ChangedDate] > '2024-01-01' part.
Note: For this to work you will need to be on >= v15.
